# taxonomy_select_nodes put order promote

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I tried to make order by promote when I call taxonomy_select_nodes. Like this:

`$node= taxonomy_select_nodes(163, TRUE,10,array('t.promote' => 'DESC','t.created' => 'DESC'));`

But I got an error! Is there any solution?
Thanks

Comment: What error you got ? Please post the error...

Comment: **taxonomy_select_nodes()** uses **taxonomy_index** table where you cant find any **promote** field. You can use `$node= taxonomy_select_nodes(163, TRUE,10,array('t.created' => 'DESC'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are using

taxonomy_select_nodes($tid, $pager = TRUE, $limit = FALSE, $order = array('t.sticky' => 'DESC', 't.created' => 'DESC'))

And Parameters

$tid: The term ID.

$pager: Boolean to indicate whether a pager should be used.

$limit: Integer. The maximum number of nodes to find. Set to FALSE for no limit.

$order: An array of fields and directions.

In your case we can see you are joining field 't.promote' it seems like the field not present, please review you code once and follow the stranded format  like https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_select_nodes/7